# Hypebolic PDE with Trigonometric coefficients

Tags: partial-differential-equations, canonical-transformation

How do I transform the following PDE into canonical form given trigonometric coefficients? I have tried the usual method using the quadratic formula but I get nowhere. Please help!

$$\cos(\theta)u_{xx}+2\sin(\theta)u_{xy}-\cos(\theta)u_{yy}$$

Note that $\theta$ does not have any restriction on it. Note comments below. We classify it as a hyperbolic PDE. I'm having trouble putting into the canonical after the you use the common technique.

Comment: Have you tried [classifying the PDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_differential_equation#Linear_equations_of_second_order)?

Comment: Note $b=2sin(\theta),a=cos(\theta),c=-cos(\theta)$ so plug into discriminant formula and get $b^2-4ac = 4sin^2(\theta)+4cos^(\theta) = 4 >0 $ So its hyperbolic. Apply the formula for transformation we get $$\frac{dy}{ds} = \frac{2sin(\theta) \pm 2}{2cos(\theta)} = tan(\theta) \pm sec(\theta)$$ Solve the odes and we get $$p = y-s(sec(\theta)+tan(\theta))$$ and $$q=y-s(sec(\theta)-tan(\theta))$$. From here I try and simpliffy the PDE as much I can in terms of p and q but I get nowhere